# windows 8 phone/C++ navigation using an array of pages

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-8, windows-phone-8

New to windows 8 phone development and trying to learn C++ in the process, i come from an actionscript 3 background, so i will explain what I’m trying to do from an as3 perspective hoping someone could shed some light on how to do this in windows 8 phone/C++ environment.

I have several pages with content page0, page1, page2 and so on, in as3 i loaded all the pages into an array called pagesList , like so

```
pagesList[0]= page0;
pagesList[1]= page1;
pagesList[2]= page2;
```

in each of these pages i have an instance of 2 MovieClips next_mc and prev_mc that is used for navigation.
The event handler checks if the target is next_mc or prev_mc and iterates through the array (back or forth) to add the respective child to the display list and remove the old page.

*pageN is an integer var to keep track of the current page.*

*removeLeft () and removeRight() functions slide out and remove the page.*

```
    public function pageNav(e:MouseEvent):void
    {           
        if(e.target is next_mc)
        {
            pageN++;
            addChild(pagesList[pageN]);
            pagesList[pageN].x= stage.stageWidth;

            removeLeft(pagesList[pageN-1]);
        }
        else if(e.target is prev_mc)
        {
            pageN--;
            addChild(pagesList[pageN]);
            pagesList[pageN].x= -pagesList[pageN].width;

            removeRight(pagesList[pageN+1]);
        }
    }
```

How could i achieve this in windows 8 phone/C++ environment, hope i have explained myself well, if anything is unclear please ask me.

Thank you, Bob.

Comment: What type of app are you trying to write? You might find it easier to make a C# Windows Phone 8 app. With a C++ WP8 app there is no built-in notion of pages (as there is with a C# WP8 app), everything is done w/ Direct3D

Comment: I was trying to do in C++ because i want to do it for iOS later on and that way i could reuse most of the code, it's multimedia type app that displays text, pics and plays music.

Comment: It's always nice to have code reuse between platforms; BUT you're going to find it much easier to display text and pictures writing a C# WP8 app. You may want to look into Xamarin as a way to share code between iOS and Windows Phone

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but my intention was to do it natively for each platform and reuse code as much as possible.
Could you point me in the right direction, to do this?

Comment: Like I said there is no concept of pages in pure C++. You need to pick a UI framework or write your own. You could look into Marmalade or Unity, but they're really meant for Games. If this is your first app I'd suggest aiming your sights a little lower. Write an app for the platform that you use, whether it be iOS, Android or Windows Phone; then worry about porting it to the other platforms.

Comment: i guess ur right, so from a C# perspective how would one do what I'm trying to do.
I used that array method to navigate the pages, couse it makes it easier to add or remove pages as needed.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: thanks but I had already seen that example, but it's very different from the way i was trying to do and i didn't know how to extrapolate it to wp8...
If u would, take a look at my example and point me to something a bit similar, pls or show me a similar example